How to keep compile times down in C
If I structure my C program like this will it keep the compile times down as the project grows?
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib/manager/manager.h"
#include "lib/loop/loop.h"
#include "lib/utility/utility.h"

int main()
{
    FN fn;
    dev_loop_init(&fn);
    dev_utility_init(&fn);

    fn.util.log("test");

    return 0;
}

A manager.h header file which I will include in every "module".
#ifndef DEV_MANAGER
#define DEV_MANAGER

typedef struct {
    void (*start) (void);
    void (*stop) (void);
} Loop;

typedef struct {
    void (*log) (char* message);
} Utility;

typedef struct {
    Loop loop;
    Utility util;
} FN;

#endif

An example module, loop.h.
#include "../manager/manager.h"

#ifndef DEV_LOOP
#define DEV_LOOP

void dev_loop_init(FN *fn);

#endif

And the loop.c functions
#include "loop.h"

static void dev_loop_start(){}

static void dev_loop_stop(){}

void dev_loop_init(FN *fn)
{
    fn->loop.start = &dev_loop_start;
    fn->loop.stop = &dev_loop_stop;
}


A usual way to manage compilation of separate files is with make

Inclusion itself is cheap, the time is spent parsing the code in the included files.  Putting everything in one header is poor design and will save you nothing, and will likely cost you.  Every translation unit that includes it will have to parse all that whether or not it uses any of it.

@Clifford, thx for reply.  I have all of the struct definitions in the manager.h file which is only added to the main.c file.  The main.c file also has all the "init" header functions.  So if I edit loop.c then it will be incremental build and only compile loop.c right?

You said explicitly "A manager.h header file which I will include in every "module"" then contradicted that in your comment.  Moreover you asked about behaviour  "as the project grows";  when your project becomes large enough for you to worry about build times, this approach will simply become unmaintainable.  Design for clarity, maintainability, maximum cohesion, minimal coupling, not some misunderstanding about build times.

Critically if all modules have a dependency on a single header, a change to that header will require a recompilation if every module, even if the change is irrelevant to most of them.  Give this nonsense up, it is not even worth discussing - just no.

Compilers are very fast and your 20-line header is not a problem at all. When your project grows to hundreds of files, usually havng thousands lines each,  you need to use the build system like make or Cmake which will compile only changed file(s)
Those systems also can run multiple instances of the compiler - compiling the code in parallel.

thank you for reply 0___, I am using VSCode and I see it has extension for makefile so I will use it. :)

@user2980746 The point of using programming IDEs isn't so much getting a fancy code editor, as in having the IDE handling all the build crap for you. So that you don't have to hack down make files manually as if living in the 1990s. If your IDE requires you to provide manual make files, it needs to be replaced. (I personally haven't used VS Code for anything serious so I wouldn't know how good/bad it is.)
